# Re-training custom NER loses info about previous labels

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a custom NER model that is working fine to find locations:

```
"I like London and Berlin"
LOC London
LOC Berlin
```

I am trying to add another custom NER training to it, following [this guide](https://spacy.io/usage/examples#new-entity-type). However, when I add a new label, the previous model loses its information about the label types. Namely:

```
"Do you like horses? I like London and Berlin"
ANIMAL horses
ANIMAL London
ANIMAL Berlin
```

(I have simply added the second sentence to the `test_text` variable in the link above, that's why no additional code is provided)

Can anybody shed some light on this? I am using spaCy 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the poor results is due to a concept called `catastrophic forgetting`. You can get more information [here](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting).

**tl;dr**

As you are training your model with new entities, it is forgetting what it previously learnt.

In order to make sure that the old learnings are not forgotten, you need to feed the model examples of the other types of entities too during retraining. By doing this, you will ensure that the model does not self tune and skew itself to predict everything as the new entity being trained.

You can read about possible solutions that can be implemented [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2204#issuecomment-382553159)

Comment: Thank you, I found out about catastrophic forgetting after asking the question. However, I may be wrong but I think this is a different phenomenon, since the NER detects the concepts correctly but labels them incorrectly.